# Can not change attribute value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following element:

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="VariableDataList[0].VariableDataForLevel[1].Value"></span>
```

I want to replace the value of `data-valmsg-for` changing the number before `.Value`. To do it, I use this function (`latestIdNumber` and `newIdNumber` are values that I compute at the beginning of the function, but imagine that `latestIdNumber` is 1 and `newIdNumber` is 2):

```
clone.find("span[data-valmsg-for$='Value']").map(function () {
    var reName = '[' + latestIdNumber + '].Value';
    $(this).attr('data-valmsg-for').replace(reName, '[' + newIdNumber + '].Value');
});
```

`reName` value is `[1].Value`. And I want to replace this text in `data-valmsg-for` with `[2].Value`. After that, I will have in `data-valmsg-for` the value `data-valmsg-for="VariableDataList[0].VariableDataForLevel[2].Value`.

I have debugged it with Visual Studio and it stops inside the find but the value of the attribute doesn't change.

I know that the attribute value doesn't change because I have opened the Internet Explorer Debugger and I don't see the new value.

I have tried the same, changing `id` and `name` for input fields and `replace` functions works perfectly.

How can I replace the value for that attribute?

Comment: These are auto generated by `ValidationMessageFor`, What are you trying to achieve? On sidenote use `.each()` not `.map()`

Comment: `.replace()` doesn't modify the string it was called on, it returns a new string. You are not using that new string.

Comment: `reName` value is `[1].Value`. And I want to replace this text in `data-valmsg-for` with `[2].Value`. After that, I will have in `data-valmsg-for` the value `data-valmsg-for="VariableDataList[0].VariableDataForLevel[2].Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should use `each()` to iterate through a collection of elements. `map()` is intended to create an array from that collection, although in this case it's not required either if you use `attr()` correctly.

The issue with your code is because you're not calling the setter of `attr()`. Instead you get the value, preform the replacement but do nothing with the result.

To fix this you can provide a function to the `attr()` method which performs the logic on each instance of the elements in the collection. Try this:

```js
var latestIdNumber = '1';
var newIdNumber = '999';
var reName = '[' + latestIdNumber + '].Value';

$("span[data-valmsg-for$='Value']").attr('data-valmsg-for', function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(reName, '[' + newIdNumber + '].Value');
});

// to show it worked:
$("span[data-valmsg-for$='Value']").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-valmsg-for'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="VariableDataList[0].VariableDataForLevel[1].Value">Foo</span>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="VariableDataList[0].VariableDataForLevel[1].Value">Bar</span>
```

Also note that you should really use the `data()` method to work with `data-*` attributes. The caveat here is that `data()` does not update the DOM, so if you require that behaviour then you would need to continue to use `attr()` as you are.

Comment: You can drop the `.each()` loop and just call `.attr()` directly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan about adding function inside method like what you put in `.attr('',function(){})` is it applicable to all function in jquery?

Comment: @guradio unfortunately not. I really wish it was as it's very handy. The pattern works for things like `attr()`, `prop()`, `css()` etc, but not for `data()`. The docs will give you details on all the methods if you want to check

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan last question which part of the docu should i search? i dont know what to search :)

Comment: You can look for a method signature that accepts a function. For `attr()` it's this one: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

Comment: The function thing couldn't work for `.data()` because a function is a valid value that can be stored *as* data. (Not that that makes it impossible, but they would have to use a non-standard signature different to the (propName, function) signature of other methods, perhaps adding a third argument to `.data()` to say whether the supplied function should be called or stored, defaulting to stored for backwards compatibility.)